# Как работают фильтры евентов в sdl

Tags: c++, sdl2

Написал небольшую обертку для окон и ивентов но наткнулся на такую проблему: при установке одновременно `SDL_AddEventWatch` (который завершает работу приложения при `SDL_QUIT` евенте) и `SDL_SetEventFilter` (который фильтрует ивенты для окна) время от времени получается так, что при закрытии последнего окна не получаю `SDL_QUIT` евент. Если же устанавливаю только `SDL_AddEventWatch`, то все работает верно (евент приходит каждый раз). В связи с этим возникает 2 вопроса:

1) `SDL_QUIT` должен генерится каждый раз при закрытии последнего окна?

2) Могут ли filter и watch конкурировать за евент? Тобишь Может ли возникать такая ситуация, когда в watch доставляется указатель на евент, а сам евент в этот же момент перезаписывается для обработки в фильтре? Ну или что-то типа того.

PS обработку евентов за пределами этих фильтров я не провожу, просто добавил `SDL_WaitEventTimeout(nullptr, 300)` для того, чтобы запускалась обработка в фильтрах

PSS 3) когда я в одном фильтре закрываю окно, то что тогда с quit эвентом? Он может не добавится в очередь?

Comment: Возможно, стоит разбить вопрос на несколько